# How do I tell if checked in file is ignored in SVN?

Tags: svn

I am going through my SVN repositories and tightening up the svn:ignore property on the directories to not report file that should be ignored.

I want to confirm that I have not added a file that is already checked in.

Although SVN handles the situation of a file being ignored and checked in just fine, it is a bit sloppy. So I want to clean it up by rem deleting the file from the repository, or adding it to the ignore list.

I am working with third-party software that does in directory builds. I have a mix of files in any particular folder (checked in and to be ignored).  There is no pattern I can exploit such as ignoring all .class files.  I am just picking the files off one by one.

Although not specific to the question, I am creating a `.svnignore` file in each directory that has at least one file to be ignored, then running:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

find . -type f -name ".svnignore" -print |while read svnignore
do
   svndir=${svnignore%/*}
   svn propset svn:ignore -F ${svnignore} ${svndir}
done
```

So, it would be great to add something to that script that would report conflicts in what I added.

Answer (score 0):

Use propget:

```
svn propget -R svn:ignore
```

The -R makes it recursive, you may not need that flag if you are doing it one at a time.